# How to access div element text based on adjacent text

Tags: html, watir

I have the following HTML code and am trying to access "QA1234", which is the value of the Serial Number. Can you let me know how I can access this text?

```
<div class="dataField">
  <div class="dataName">
    <span id="langSerialNumber">Serial Number</span>
  </div>
  <div class="dataValue">QA1234</div>
</div>

<div class="dataField">
  <div class="dataName">
    <span id="langHardwareRevision">Hardware Revision</span>
  </div>
  <div class="dataValue">05</div>
</div>

<div class="dataField">
  <div class="dataName">
    <span id="langManufactureDate">Manufacture Date</span>
  </div>
  <div class="dataValue">03/03/2011</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are trying to get the "QA1234" text in terms of being the "Serial Number". If that is correct, you basically need to:

1. Locate the "dataField" div that includes the serial number span.
2. Get the "dataValue" within that div.

One way is to get all the "dataField" divs and find the one that includes the span:

```
parent = browser.divs(class: 'dataField').find { |div| div.span(id: 'langSerialNumber').exists? }
p parent.div(class: 'dataValue').text
#=> "QA1234"

parent = browser.divs(class: 'dataField').find { |div| div.span(id: 'langManufactureDate').exists? }
p parent.div(class: 'dataValue').text
#=> "03/03/2011"
```

Another option is to find the serial number span and then traverse up to the parent "dataField" div:

```
parent = browser.span(id: 'langSerialNumber').parent.parent
p parent.div(class: 'dataValue').text
#=> "QA1234"

parent = browser.span(id: 'langManufactureDate').parent.parent
p parent.div(class: 'dataValue').text
#=> "03/03/2011"
```

I find the first approach to be more robust to changes since it is more flexible to how the serial number is nested within the "dataField" div. However, for pages with a lot of fields, it may be less performant.